# Adding accumulative value in excel based on unique ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I just created a spreadsheet with a list of names that all have their own individual unique ID associated. The purpose of this sheet this spreadsheet track to keep track of a point reward system. This is a running entry sheet which means each a individual may be re-entered several times whenever a point(s) are entered. What I would like to do if possible, is to automatically add the accumulative points based on the unique id's as they are entered. Current this is down manually.

[image: Sample]

Comment: post a small data sample and mock up the desired results manually. Also post what you have tried. Edit your question to do that, then post a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMIFS with a variable range.

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:B2,$A$2:A2,A2)
```

Pay attention to what is and what is not an absolute reference.  As this formula is dragged/copied down the sheet the relative range references will change leaving the absolute anchored.

[image]

Comment: I'm running into an issue. In "Q" my value comes from the current formula:  =IF(I1304="Putaway Error","2",IF(I1304="Replenishment Error","2",IF(I1304="Mispick","5",IF(I1304="Product in Wrong Location","2",IF(I1304="Leftoff","8",IF(I1304="Receiving Error","2",IF(I1304="Mixed Location","2",IF(I1304="Keying Error","8",IF(I1304="Incorrect Damage Process","2",IF(I1304="Significant Process Error","8",IF(I1304="Miscellaneous","1",IF(I1304="Inbound Discrepancy","4",""))))))))))))      So I'm getting a "0" with =SUMIFS($Q$1304:Q1304,$G$1304:G1304,G1304)..but if I manually enter the value it works. Thks

Comment: @YurieAmes remove the `""` around the numbers of your formula.  It is inserting the numbers as text and not a number.  SUMIFS will ignore text.